# Is it possible to tree shake unused libphonenumber-js from class-validator in Vite.js production build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, class-validator

The maintainer of `class-validator` says the library is written in a tree-shakable way. https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1803

I do not use the `IsPhoneNumber()` decorator or function at all in my react app, so in theory the `libphonenumber-js` should not be included in the bundle but it does:

[image]

Is there any way to exclude libphonenumber-js from the bundle?

Here is part of the viteconfig.ts:

```
{
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          entryFileNames: `assets/[hash].js`,
          chunkFileNames: `assets/[hash].js`,
          assetFileNames: `assets/[hash].[ext]`,
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      react({
        babel: {
          parserOpts: {
            plugins: ["decorators-legacy", "classProperties"],
          },
          plugins: [
            [
              babelOptimizerPlugin, {}
            ],
          ],
        },
      }),
      VitePWA(),
      splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
      resolve: {
      alias: {
         typeorm: "/node_modules/typeorm/typeorm-model-shim",
         "type-graphql": "/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/browser-shim.js",
             },
       },
    ],
  }
```